# Outlook 2010 does not include style tag in signature

Tags: html, outlook, responsive-design, html-email, outlook-2010

I have issue to create HTML signature emails for Outlook.

I have a style tag before signature and add media width for responsive email.

```
<style type="text/css">
div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

table {
min-width:650px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
td[class=hidden-phone] {
    width: 0px !important;
    display: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    float: left !important;
}
td[class=description] {
    width: 100% !important;
}

td[class=visible-phone] {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    float:none !important;
}
table {
    min-width: auto !important;
}
}
</style>

<table width="100%" style="font-family:'arial';">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" width="100%" style="height:10px;border-bottom:2px solid #96999e;height:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:10px;width:80px;min-width:80px;"><img src="http://urbanangles.com/fileserver/gallery/[[ID]]_original.png" /></td>
<td class="description" valign="bottom" style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px;width:170px;color:#111;min-width:170px;line-height:11px;">
    <span style="font-size:11px"><strong>[[NAME]]</strong></span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:11px;color:#007dc3;">[[TITLE]]</span><div style="margin-bottom:5px;"></div>
    <span style="font-size:9px;">A Studio</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:9px;">10 Somewhere St, Suburb, STA&nbsp;1234</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:9px;margin-right:10px;">D&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:9px;">[[DIRECT]]</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:9px;margin-right:10px;">P&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:9px;">[[PHONE]]</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:9px;margin-right:9px;">M&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:9px;">[[MOBILE]]</span><br/>
    <span style="font-size:9px;margin-right:10px;">E&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size:9px;"><a href="mailto:[[EMAIL]]" style="color:#111;text-decoration:none;">[[EMAIL]]</a></span><div style="margin-bottom:5px;height:0px;"></div>
    <span style="font-size:11px"><strong><a style="color:#111;text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.examples.com">www.examples.com</a></strong></span><br/>
</td>
<td class="hidden-phone" style="width:100%;"></td>
<td class="hidden-phone" valign="bottom" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 0;width:360px;min-width:360px;"><span style="margin-right:15px;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/urbanangles" style="margin-right:3px;"><img src="http://william.uadev.com.au/img/facebook.jpg" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.twitter.com/urban_angles"><img src="http://william.uadev.com.au/img/twitter.jpg" /></a></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.urbanangles.com"><img src="http://william.uadev.com.au/img/logo.jpg" /></a>    </td>
 </tr>
 <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
 <tr>
<td colspan="1" width="100%" class="visible-phone" style="max-height:0;display:none;height:0;overflow:hidden;width:0;float:left">
    <span style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:25px;">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/examples" style="margin-right:5px;"><img src="http://william.uadev.com.au/img/facebook.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/examples"><img src="http://william.uadev.com.au/img/twitter.jpg" /></a></span>
</td>
<td colspan="3" width="100%" class="visible-phone" style="max-height:0;display:none;height:0;overflow:hidden;width:0;float:left">
    <a href="http://www.urbanangles.com"><img src="http://william.uadev.com.au/img/logo" style="width:80%;margin-left:8px;" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
<!--<![endif]-->
<tr><td colspan="4" width="100%" style="height:10px;border-top:2px solid #96999e;"></td>   </tr>
</table>

<p  style="font-size:11px;font-family:'arial';margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:0"><i>Please consider the environment before printing this email.</i></p>

<p style="font-size:9px;font-family:'arial';color:#999;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:0">This email and any attachment(s) is intended only for the exclusive and confidential use of the addressee(s). If you are not the intended recipient, any use, interference with, disclosure or copying of this material is unauthorised and prohibited. If you have received this message in error, please notify the sender by return email immediately and delete the message from your computer without making any copies. [[COMPANY]] does not guarantee the integrity of any emails or attached files.</p>
```

I got everything working fine on apple mail. However, outlook does not look happy with my html. All emails from outlook will not have the style tag which makes my html looks weird on iphone.

My questions:

1. Why the style tag is not included in my email? From what I know it is supported in outlook. See ref [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)
2. Is there any work around or fixes that I can do? I would love to have responsive email work on iPhone and I know it is working if I send it from Apple Mail.

Cheers,
Will

Comment: Can you provide the html as well?

Comment: From your the documentation you provided in #1, Outlook does not support the method in which you are declaring your CSS. E[foo="bar"] vs E.foo

Answer (score 1):

If the style tag is not appearing in the code of your email, it might be because it is not in the head. Not sure if this is needed for Outlook, but this might be why it is getting stripped out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is it possible to add style into the head from signature? I tried several different ways but no luck..

Comment: You could try putting some code at the top of your email, but that would make it not in the signature. I think you might be fighting a losing battle unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The `<style>` tag is stripped out from some email clients such as Gmail, (maybe Outlook is doing the same?)

Instead you should use in-line styles.

From the same website you quoted, guidelines for using styles: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/

You can use http://premailer.dialect.ca/ to convert your signiture to have inline styles, and its free :)

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for the answers. I used inline style in html. However, I need a responsive signature for the company which requires media query. I do not think (or know) media query can be attached as inline style. I understand that will not work in all email clients but I only concern in IOS devices as I stated above.

Comment: It should be fine, try it out and let us know what happens

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the HTML email boilerplate.

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should always use in-line styles for HTML e-mails as this gives the most compatibility with different clients. I know it's not as nice as separate CSS block, but that's the way it is.